# for item in data: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, kivy

I need to create a search and autofill mobile app in Kivy, in which a list of toppings will be added to the list box. When I type the text in the input text, the relevant items will be shown in the list box for choosing.
py file
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock

```
Builder.load_file('search_autofill.kv')

Window.size = (350, 600)

toppings = ['Pepperoni', 'Cheese','Papper', 
            'Hawaii','Seafood', "Ham", 'Taco','Onion']

class MainApp(App):
    title='Search Autofill'
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)
        Window.clearcolor = (51/255, 153/255, 1, 1) 
        return Mylayout()  

    def update(self, data):
        pass
        # Clear the listbox
        self.root.ids.list_entry.text = ''

        # Add toppings into the list
        for item in data:
            self.root.ids.list_entry.text = item

    # Update entry box with listbox clicked
    def fillout(self, e):
        # Delete whatever is in the entry box
        self.root.ids.my_entry.text = ''
        
        # Add clicked list item to the entry box
        self.root.ids.my_entry.text(self.root.ids.list_entry.text)

    def check(self, e):
        # grab the typed item
        typed = self.root.ids.my_entry.text
        if typed == '':
            data = toppings
        else:
            data = []
            for item in toppings:
                if typed.lower() in item.lower():
                    data.append(item)
   

class Mylayout(Widget):  
    pass  
           
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
        
        kv file
        <MyLayout>
                      
            FloatLayout:
                
                Label:
                    id: label_frame
                    text: 'Start typing....'
                    pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':5}
                    size_hint: (2, .4)
                    color: 'black'
                    font_size: 15
        
                TextInput:
                    id: my_entry
                    text: ''
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 15
                    pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':4.5}
                    size_hint: (2, .4)
                    halign: "left"
                    focus: True
                    color: 'black'
              TextInput:
                   id: list_entry
                   text: ''
                   multiline: True
                   font_size: 15
                   pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':1.5}
                   size_hint: (2, 2.5)
                   halign: "left"
                   color: 'black'
                   on_text_validate: app.update()
```

When I run the py, following error is incurred:
File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\search_autofill.py", line 78, in 
MainApp().run()
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
runTouchApp()
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
EventLoop.mainloop()
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
self.idle()
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 387, in idle
Clock.tick()
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 733, in tick
self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())
File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
self._process_events()
File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 616, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 645, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\search_autofill.py", line 28, in update
for item in data:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Check the content of variable 'data' when 'update(self, data)' is called.
'update' is expecting data to be iterable object (Ex: list, tuple etc) but looks a single float value passed as 'data'.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to schedule (which is the origin of the problem) the method `update` in `build` when you already bind it to `on_text_validate` (which suggests that you need it only after proper validation) ? Also is not `multiline` supposed to be `False` in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not really sure what you were trying to do cuz your code provides little to no clue but here's what i understand, you want to write in the upper text field and have it fill in the lower text box automatically. if that was the direction you were heading in. then there is no need to call the `update` function in the build none the less using clock schedule. clock schedule passes and arbitrary function which is the interval of the schedule. in this case that value was `1.1209118089999999` or something close and the `data` variable in the `update` function received this value hence why

```
   for item in data:
        self.root.ids.list_entry.text = item
```

throws an error cuz you are trying to iterate through a float value.
from what i came up with, this line `Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)` is not required.

you should do something like this(most of the work did was in the `update` function):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
Window.size = (350, 600)

toppings = ['Pepperoni', 'Cheese','Papper',
            'Hawaii','Seafood', "Ham", 'Taco','Onion']

class MainApp(App):
    title='Search Autofill'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.load_kv("main.kv")

    def build(self):
        # Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)
        Window.clearcolor = (51/255, 153/255, 1, 1)
        return Mylayout()

    def on_start(self):
        self.update(toppings)

    def update(self, data):

        if isinstance(data, list):
            for item in data:
                self.root.ids.list_entry.text = item if self.root.ids.list_entry.text == '' else self.root.ids.list_entry.text + "\n" + item
        else:
            self.root.ids.list_entry.text = ''
            if data == "":
                self.update(toppings)
            else:
                new_toppings_list = [x.lower() for x in toppings]
                data = [string for string in new_toppings_list if data.lower() in string]
                if len(data) != 0:
                    for item in data:
                        self.root.ids.list_entry.text = item.capitalize() if self.root.ids.list_entry.text == '' else self.root.ids.list_entry.text + "\n" + item.capitalize()
                else:
                    self.root.ids.list_entry.text = "Not found in list"

    # Update entry box with listbox clicked
    def fillout(self, e):
        # Delete whatever is in the entry box
        self.root.ids.my_entry.text = ''

        # Add clicked list item to the entry box
        self.root.ids.my_entry.text = self.root.ids.list_entry.text



class Mylayout(Widget):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

as you can see i removed the `check` function. it is no longer needed.
i do not understand what you intend to do with the `fillout` function though given that you using a textfield to list items. i suppose you cant click one item on the list to fillout the entry textfield

and your kv file

```
<MyLayout>
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: label_frame
            text: 'Start typing....'
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            color: 'black'
            font_size: 15

        TextInput:
            id: my_entry
            text: ''
            multiline: False
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':4.5}
            size_hint: (2, .4)
            halign: "left"
            focus: True
            color: 'black'
            on_text: app.update(self.text)
        TextInput:
            id: list_entry
            text: ''
            multiline: True
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':1.5}
            size_hint: (2, 2.5)
            halign: "left"
            color: 'black'
```